# How can get the text enclosed by a span tag and save it to a hidden input value when I click the span?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I need to put the text enclosed by a span tag in my hidden input when I click that span tag.

This is my code I have:

```
<tr class="vevnumdays">
<td class="vevfree" align="center"><span class="vevmonthday">15</span></td>
<td class="vevfree" align="center"><span class="vevmonthday">16</span></td>
<td class="vevfree" align="center"><span class="vevmonthday">17</span></td>
</tr>
<input name="startdate" id="startdate" type="hidden" class="sv_date_box" value="Select a Date"/>
```

How can do it using jquery click?

Comment: nevermind didnt see it

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$('.vevmonthday').click(function()
{
    $("#startdate").val($(this).text());
});
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/xjekbv13/

Answer (score 0):

This should work - https://jsfiddle.net/ToddNewent/z4cd04tj/

```
$('.vevmonthday').on('click',function(){
    $('#startdate').val($(this).text());
});
```

It takes the inner text of the span .vevmonthday and sets the #startdate to that value.